# Any way to get what port is my app using?

Tags: android, mobile

I've search a lot and I can't get which port is my app using.

I tried using `adb shell netstat -n` but I'm not sure if this command is showing me anything related to my app.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. Is the app not yours? if it's yours, just check the code that compiles it to see which port you are using?

Comment: Where can I see that? Maybe I didn't explain myself well.

I'm making my service requests through a GraphQL client and Retrofit, in none of these I specified the port. By not specifying it, do they use a default port? Can I check what port is that?

Comment: Your question is too broad and lacking key information needed. If you are creating a server-client based mechanism that is using network protocols you need to specify a port. If you are trying to connect to an existing service you'll need to read through that service's documentation to see the port used. If no such documentation exists it means you probably shouldn't connect to it that way to begin with, unless you are trying some sort of a hacking operation, in that case I don't think that's the correct place for this question.